# Filtering out list of sequential values in R?

Tags: r

I have a tibble, called zero_sum_ab. Each is identified with the variable ab_id. I am trying to isolate nonsequential values... for example, see the snippet below:

[image: see screenshot of tibble w/ Highlighted values]

In the image, you can see the ab_id's are mostly non-sequential. Scattered throughout the data are sequential values, like the ones highlighted: 2015000110 and 2015000111.

What I am trying to do is filter out the **second** value from these groups of sequential pairs from the overall dataset. My thought is to isolate the second values in their own list and use it to filter the overall dataset for the values I need, but am struggling to find a way to do this.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the sequential records, try

```
library(dplyr)
zero_sum_ab %>% filter((ab_id - lag(ab_id)) == 1)
```

If you want to discard the sequential records, try

```
library(dplyr)
zero_sum_ab %>% filter(!(ab_id - lag(ab_id)) == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... I can see now how my wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: @r2evans I think OP was conveying that OP now understood that `filter out the second value` was ambiguous. It could mean keep or discard the second value depending on how you read it. It's likely OP just doesn't understand the checkmark-is-accepted-answer system rather than is soliciting more answers.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't looked at it that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to CPak's:

```r
dat <- data.frame(ab_id = c(2015000099, 2015000103, 2015000106, 2015000110, 2015000111, 2015000112, 2015000116, 2015000119))
dat
#        ab_id
# 1 2015000099
# 2 2015000103
# 3 2015000106
# 4 2015000110
# 5 2015000111
# 6 2015000112
# 7 2015000116
# 8 2015000119

dat[ c(TRUE, diff(dat$ab_id) != 1L),, drop = FALSE]
#        ab_id
# 1 2015000099
# 2 2015000103
# 3 2015000106
# 4 2015000110
# 7 2015000116
# 8 2015000119
```

Similarly, in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(c(TRUE, diff(ab_id) != 1L))
#        ab_id
# 1 2015000099
# 2 2015000103
# 3 2015000106
# 4 2015000110
# 5 2015000116
# 6 2015000119
```

(`diff` is just a base-R simplification of `val - dplyr::lag(val)`)

Comment: I think `diff()` is cleaner as well